# How to distinguish between handwritten ソ and ン?

Tags: handwriting

I often get confused in distinguishing between the handwritten ソ and ン. Is there any hint to do so easily?

I know the stroke order for both in writing so what I want to know is how to distinguish between them in reading.

Comment: See http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13846/difference-between-katakana-so-and-n (and also http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/distinguishing-certain-characters-in-handwriting-and-print-similar-looking-kana)