# Could the animal "lion" be represented by シ or by ツ

Tags: translation

Looking at an old world war two map, I know there is a mountain/hill/ridge which was nicknamed "lion" by the Japanese. The old map has a Japanese symbol written on the spot of that mountain/hill/ridge.

Because I don't know Japanese (can't recognize and understand the characters), I don't know which one of the following characters it might be:

Either:

> シ

or

> ツ

Could someone with knowledge of Japanese give me a definite answer on which one it might likely be, and why.

Drawing from my knowledge of Chinese, my best guess is it will be

> シ

because it seems that this Japanese character is pronounced "**shi**", which might be coming from the Chinese "**獅**子" (**shi** zi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[獅子](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%8D%85%E5%AD%90) is a dated word that means *lion* in Japanese. This can also be written as しし in hiragana and シシ (shi-shi) in katakana.

シ can ツ can be distinguished [like this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/33579/5010). [ツツ/つつ/筒](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%AD%92) means *pipe*, by the way.